# Fabric Log in with twitter button is greyed out

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I followed the instructions using Fabric to implement my sign in in my custom app.

The problem is that when i run my app the button is greyed out.

Here are the errors on my stack trace:

```
03-20 11:06:32.456    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/Twitter﹕ Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()

03-20 11:06:32.546    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
03-20 11:06:32.556    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
03-20 11:06:32.556    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
03-20 11:06:32.556    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
03-20 11:06:32.556    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
03-20 11:06:32.566    6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
```

But i also initialized fabric in my activity.

Here's a snippet:

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//copied key and secret from fabric
private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "my key here"; 
private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "my secret here";

private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Twitter */
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    /* Twitter */
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/* Twitter */
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

You have to initialize Fabric *before* inflating the Twitter button. Because otherwise when Twitter button constructor is called it doesn't know how to connect twitter api. This is what the error description says in a nutshell.

```
6509-6509/com.jan.simplesharing E/Twitter﹕ Must Initialize Fabric before using singleton()
```

In general, you can initialize Fabric at the `Application` class. This is what they do at their sample showcase app: https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/fabric/samples/cannonball/App.java#L98

Comment: What about to use it from On Reboot Broadcast Receiver ? Because till then we will not have application context to initialize it.

Comment: Check android lifecycle documentation. Application class is always created before anything else does. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()

Comment: add these line before setContentView `TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("KEY", "SECRET_KEY");
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
`

Comment: i added into my application class and now its working fine...Thank you @SergiiPechenizkyi...!!!

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to achieve twitter login using Fabric :

Create a class which extends Application class and copy the following    code into it -

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

Fabric.with() performs the functionality of initializing.
Do no forget to mention this application class in your android manifest file

```
 <application
    android:name="com.demoapp.BaseApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you have replaced the TWITTER_KEY and TWITTER_SECRET with your application's keys?

---

If not,you should register a twitter application on https://apps.twitter.com/ and use the keys the platform provides you. Also, make sure you're following the steps of the tutorial (https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/configure) for your app config.

Comment: Link not available